# android twitter

Tags: android, twitter

i am developing and application in which i want to get some feeds from twitter like picture, name, tweets, time and number of reply on each tweet. i did all but could not get number of reply for each tweet.... help me out thanks in advance.. 
i am posting my code also.

```
Twitter unauthenticatedTwitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
                 Paging paging = new Paging(1, 100);
                 List<twitter4j.Status> statuses = unauthenticatedTwitter.getUserTimeline("BeingSalmanKhan",paging);

                         for (Status status3 : statuses) 
                          {
                             TwitterFeeds tFeeds = new TwitterFeeds();
                                 System.out.println(status3.getText());
                                 tFeeds.strTweet = status3.getText();
                                 tFeeds.strDate  = status3.getCreatedAt().toString();
                                 System.out.println("---------------------------------- " + status3.getSource());

                                 al_tweets.add(tFeeds);

                          }
                         str_tw_name    =   unauthenticatedTwitter.showUser("BeingSalmanKhan").getName();
                         str_tw_imgurl  =   unauthenticatedTwitter.showUser("BeingSalmanKhan").getProfileImageURL().toString();



                         bitmap_twpic = NewsActivity.DownloadImage(str_tw_imgurl);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this snippet of code... it worked for me.. hope for you too

```
try {
                   Twitter unauthenticatedTwitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
                   //URLEntity[] uent= 
                 //First param of Paging() is the page number, second is the number per page (this is capped around 200 I think.
                 Paging paging = new Paging(1, 100);
                 List<twitter4j.Status> statuses = unauthenticatedTwitter.getUserTimeline("ashabhosle",paging);
                 System.out.println("status no 2 ="+statuses.get(2).toString());
                 long retweetcnt=statuses.get(2).getRetweetCount();
                 System.out.println("retweet count on 2nd tweet "+retweetcnt);
                         for (Status status3 : statuses) 
                          {
                                 System.out.println(status3.getText());
                          }
            } 
               catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Failed to get timeline: " + e.getMessage());

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

try getRelatedResults(),gives a list of replies + mentions,it is the closest to getting replies.

Comment: it takes long as parameter and i have a screen name which is string... plz tell me how to use this method...